# How to reset the counter automatically after 3rd count by using Cd4026 counter IC and 555 IC?

Tags: circuit-analysis, counter

How to reset cd4026 counter automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The CD4026 has a reset pin which is active high, which means to reset the counter, you just toggle the reset pin high.

For example, if you wanted it to happen after 8 counts (0-7), when it gets to 7 (0-1-1-1), you need to reset it on the next step. It's up to you how you do this, as we are not a free design service. All you really need to know is toggle the RESET pin high to start the counter again.